# Change file address

Tags: c#, .net, io

suppose we have `c:\\d1\\d2\\d3\\...` where there are many files and directories in `d3`.
we want to move all items in `d3` to `c:\\d1\\new\\`.

how to do it clean and safe?

`c:\\d1\\new` exists!

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to physically move the files, or that you want to know how to change all the references to the old path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `c:\d1\new` does not exist yet, and you don't want to keep an empty `c:\d1\d2\d3` folder afterward, you can use the [Directory.Move()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx) method:

```
using System.IO;

try {
    Directory.Move(@"c:\d1\d2\d3", @"c:\d1\new");
} catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) {
    // Permission denied, recover...
} catch (IOException) {
    // Other I/O error, recover...
}
```

If `c:\d1\new` does exist, you'll have to iterate over the contents of `c:\d1\d2\d3` and move its files and folders one by one:

```
foreach (string item in Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(@"c:\d1\d2\d3")) {
    string absoluteSource = Path.Combine(@"c:\d1\d2\d3", item);
    string absoluteTarget = Path.Combine(@"c:\d1\new", item);
    if (File.GetAttributes(absoluteSource) & FileAttributes.Directory != 0) {
        Directory.Move(absoluteSource, absoluteTarget);
    } else {
        File.Move(absoluteSource, absoluteTarget);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the only instruction a monkey might even be able to follow.

Comment: If `c:\d1\new` exists, you'll have to iterate over the contents of `c:\d1\d2\d3` and move its files and folders one by one using the same function.

Comment: @hamidi: I was looking for a better solution for this issue.

Comment: @HPT: Well, as with the initial question, some context was presumed, now you're making answerers have to do it again - give some context, one might say overwrite, the other rename existing, I say to-mato, you say to-mayto!

Answer (score 2):

Use [Directory.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx)

Also, MSDN has a handy table of what functions to use for [Common I/O Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278.aspx) which is a good reference for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
    System.IO.Directory.Move(@"c:\d1\d2\d3\", @"c:\d1\new\");
}
catch(...)
{
}
```

The Move method can throw any of the following exceptions that depending on your usage may or may not be thrown.  So you need to code the exception handler in a manner that suits your application.

- System.IO.IOExeption
- System.UnauthorizedAccessException
- System.ArgumentException
- System.ArgumentNullException
- System.IO.PathToLongException
- System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

As an general example (you probably don't want/need to display message boxes on errors):

```
try
{
    System.IO.Directory.Move(@"c:\d1\d2\d3\", @"c:\d1\new\");
}
catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You do not have access to move this files/directories");
}
catch(System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The directory to move files/directories from was not found")
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Something blew up!");
}
```

Finally, it is worth mentioning that the call to Move will block the current thread until the move is complete.  So if you are doing this from a UI it will block the UI until the copy is complete.  This might take some time depending on how many files/directories are being move.  Therefore it might be prudent to run this in a seperate thread and/or display a cycling progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Directory.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx).

> Moves a file or a directory and its contents to a new location.